# Can I create a List<WeakReference<T>>?

Tags: c#, generics, weak-references

I'm trying to create a List of `WeakReference`s using the 4.5 generic implementation so that I can avoid type checking and casting of the `WeakReference` target.  But, `WeakReference<T>` doesn't appear to support covariance, so I'm trying to establish a workaround.

I'm thinking it should be doable since each T would be of a type in a particular inheritance chain.  So, what I'm thinking would be along these lines:

```
public class Animal { }
public class Tiger : Animal { }
public class Wolf : Animal { }

var mylist = new List<WeakReference<Animal>>();

mylist.Add(new WeakReference<Animal>(new Animal()));
mylist.Add(new WeakReference<Tiger>(new Tiger()));
mylist.Add(new WeakReference<Wolf>(new Wolf()));
```

I've tried creating a wrapper class for WeakReference (since it's non-inheritable), but that doesn't work.  No matter what, the list won't accept any typed `WeakReference` other than `WeakReference<Animal>`.

I could create my own generic `WeakReference` implementation, but that would seem to be defeating the point since I'd be doing type casting within it.  I can't find any documentation, but I'm kind of assuming the framework version handles this better.

Is there another way of handling this that I'm not thinking of, or am I barking up the wrong tree?

Comment: `WeakReference<T>` doesn't define the generic paramter `T` as covariant; you can add a `new WeakReference<Animal>(new Wolf())` to your collection.

Comment: Classes are never covariant; only interfaces and delegates can be. And anyway, `WeakReference<T>` couldn't be covariant, since `T` appears both in input and output position.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`WeakReference` is invariant, since it allows the value to be set, and that wouldn't be valid if it were covariant.  To make it covariant you'll need to make a read only wrapper around the reference, and also use an interface.

```
public interface IReadOnlyWeakReference<out T>
{
    T Value { get; }
}

public class WeakReferenceWrapper<T> : IReadOnlyWeakReference<T>
    where T : class
{
    private WeakReference<T> reference;
    public WeakReferenceWrapper(WeakReference<T> reference)
    {
        this.reference = reference;
    }

    public T Value
    {
        get
        {
            T output;
            if (reference.TryGetTarget(out output))
                return output;
            else
                return default(T);
        }
    }
}
```

An extension method for the conversion is also somewhat convenient:

```
public static IReadOnlyWeakReference<T> AsReadOnly<T>(
    this WeakReference<T> reference)
    where T : class
{
    return new WeakReferenceWrapper<T>(reference);
}
```

Now we can write:

```
var mylist = new List<IReadOnlyWeakReference<Animal>>();

mylist.Add(new WeakReference<Animal>(new Animal()).AsReadOnly());
mylist.Add(new WeakReference<Tiger>(new Tiger()).AsReadOnly());
mylist.Add(new WeakReference<Wolf>(new Wolf()).AsReadOnly());
```

Comment: Now next question, how to use it?

Comment: No, how to consume the list? OP will be still getting `Value` as `Animal` only right as the list is of `IReadOnlyWeakReference<Animal>` type.

Comment: Very nearly identical to the wrapper I was creating.  Using the interface definition in the List seemed to be the missing key.

Answer (score 2):

You could simply use `WeakReference<Animal>` itself, anyways list is of type `List<WeakReference<Animal>>`, so you even with the covariance, you'll not be able to access the more derived members.

```
var mylist = new List<WeakReference<Animal>>();    
mylist.Add(new WeakReference<Animal>(new Animal()));
mylist.Add(new WeakReference<Animal>(new Tiger()));
mylist.Add(new WeakReference<Animal>(new Wolf()));
```

Or if you prefer to keep the more specific type, there is a way. I've solved it earlier with visitor pattern. [See if that helps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23250839/2530848).

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to create a list of WeakReferences (List) and expose it as an IEnumerable like this:

```
private List<WeakReference> innerList = new List<WeakReference>();

public IEnumerable<T> List
{
    get
    {
        return (this.innerList.Where(x => x.Target is T).Select(x => (T) x.Target));
    }
}
```