# Use a generic parameter and store it in a weak reference

Tags: c#, generics, weak-references

I want to use a `WeakReference` and want to pass a generic type to it.

```
public class SomeDataSource : UICollectionViewDataSource
{
    private WeakReference<T> weakController;

    public SomeDataSource (T controller)
    {
        this.weakController = new WeakReference<T>(controller);
    }
}
```

When I want to access my controller I have to know the type. I thought about something like this:

```
if (typeof(SomeViewController) == weakController.GetType ()) {
    SomeViewController controller;
    if (weakController.TryGetTarget (out controller)) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Is this possible? Currently I'm getting

> The type or namespace name 'T' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?

everywhere I used `T`. My researched showed this

- [Can I create a `List<WeakReference<T>>`?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27301626/426227)
- [Generic WeakReference](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22363/Generic-WeakReference)
- [Strongly-typed WeakReference](http://blog.somewhatabstract.com/2012/03/24/strongly-typed-weakreference/)

but I don't know if I have to use something like this.

Comment: `T` has to be included in the class definition: `public class SomeDataSource<T>` Afterwards you can just use `typeof(T)` in any function inside the SomeDataSource class

Comment: If I use it in the class definition I get many more compile errors, because I don't have defined the type yet. I don't quite understand the impacts of using this.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should just use `WeakReference<object>` which can store any object reference.

Comment: I get *cannot convert 'out SomeViewController' expression to type 'out object'* on `TryGetTarget()`. Do I have to use a type cast here? At which step?

Comment: Type the variable as object and cast only later.

Answer (score 1):

I can't test it at the moment, but you could do something like

```
public class SomeDataSource : UICollectionViewDataSource
{
    private WeakReference<object> weakController;

    public SomeDataSource (object controller)
    {
        this.weakController = new WeakReference<object>(controller);
    }
}
```

And then

```
object o;
SomeViewController controller;
if (weakController.TryGetTarget(out o)) 
{
    controller = o as SomeViewController;

    // do something
}
```

Comment: I did that as *usr* mentioned it. The only difference is that I defined *SomeViewController* in `TryGetTarget()`. It does work, but my app crashes where it didn't before. I've to look deeper into this, but perhaps I need another way (without using generic parameters and weak reference at all).

Comment: What does crash after this change?

Comment: It shouldn't be related with this question, but here it is: *UICollectionView received layout attributes for a cell with an index path that does not exist*. If I use `WeakReference` it doesn't crash, but if I use `WeakReference<object>` it does.