# Invoking generic method/delegate from a non-generic base class

Tags: c#, generics

I have the feeling I'm not looking at this issue from the right angle here, and I'm just not thinking of other solution.

Assuming this generic class;

```
public abstract class Port<T>
{
    public delegate T PullDelegate();

    private PullDelegate pull;

    public Port(PullDelegate pull)
    {
        this.pull = pull;
    }

    public T Pull()
    {
        return pull();
    }
}
```

It is used to define "ports" in a graph-node editor. A port can transfer a object/value from one node to another, but they also need to be "type-safe", which means I cannot plug any port to another of the wrong type (at least not without some conversion).

The node "owns" a port and give it a delegate towards one of its method so when another node "pull" on a value, the port simply invokes it and returns the proper value.

My issue starts when I'm trying to call `Pull()` from a non-generic collection. Obviously, I could make a non-generic base method, but then Pull could not return `T`, it would need to return `object`.

Also, each nodes have collection accessors for their ports so the other items can get them. That collect has to be non-generic because a node can have many ports of many type.

```
    public abstract Port[] Inputs { get; }
    public abstract Port[] Outputs { get; }
    public abstract Port[] Entries { get; }
    public abstract Port[] Exits { get; }
```

The moment the non-generic type get into play, everything generic become inaccessible. If only `Port<>[]` would be a thing.

I'm feeling like I'm missing something...

Comment: You could create an `IPort<out T> { T Pull(); }` then create an `IEnumerable<Port<object>>`.

Comment: What about your objects would all implement one interface so you could be sure it's gonna be at least and object that implements that, would that change your situation? So you could avoid using objects but rather something like IMyObject.

Comment: Is `Port` base class of `Port<T>`? How exactly you'd like to use the non generic collection?

Comment: Sometime ago, I solved such a problem with [Visitor Pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23250839/2530848). See if that helps, Or show your use case, I'll try to adapt the solution to your requirement. [Here's another sample of same pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33409364/calling-a-generic-method-with-interface-instances)

Comment: @SriramSakthivel : I'm not sure yet. My first idea was to do `Port<T> : Port`. Right now, I'm trying Lee's suggestion with `IPort<object>`.

Comment: `IPort<out T>` won't work when `T` is a value type. If you have `Port<T> : Port`, or `Port<T> : IPort`, my visitor pattern idea will help.

Comment: @Lee: Damn. I'm getting ArrayTypeMismatchException while doing `return new IPort<object>[] { output };`.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel : Correct me if I'm wrong, but the visitor pattern would assume I have know all the potential type of `T` ahead of time, no? If someone implement a new `Port<Potato>` without me knowing, it would simply break?

Comment: Without knowing how you want to use and what are you going to do with the return value, Hard to comment on that. Update your question with that information. That will help to me answer your question.

Comment: @LightStriker - Arrays are invariant so you have to use a covariant collection type like `IEnumerable<IPort<object>>` or `IReadOnlyCollection<IPort<object>>`. If you need to make the collections mutable you won't be able to use this approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make `Port<T>` implement the non-generic interface `IPort` using explicit implementations. In that way it's hidden from the API but still allow you to invoke methods in the generic classes.

```
public interface IPort
{
    object SomeAction(object data);
}

public class Port<T> : IPort
{
    //[.. all other methods ..]


    object IPort.SomeAction(object data)
    {
        var typedData = (T)data;
        //invoke our typed version.
        return SomeAction(data);
    }

    public T SomeAction(T data)
    {
         // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: If my issue was simply to pass something to it, I wouldn't bother with generics. The issue I have is I'm getting something from it. Assume your `SomeAction` returns `T`.

Comment: @LightStriker: What about returning object from IPort.SomeAction and T from IPort<T>.SomeAction (with IPort<T> implementing IPort)?  I think that's what they do in IEnumerable/IEnumerable<T>.

Comment: @jgauffin Actually, I did what Devstruck proposed with a IPort/IPort<T> similar to how IEnumerable are implemented in List<T>. It works. I just noticed that the generic IPort<T> might not be actually needed in how I'm using it right now. I'll probably keep it just in case. Thanks.